# Visiting a website

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Which phrasal verbs or verbs can be used when mentioned visiting a website on the Internet?

For example, I would like to say

> I have not visited this website for months.

Can I say

> I haven't ***got on*** this website for months.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One view of the Internet treats websites like any other physical location:

> I haven't **visited** this website in a while
>
> I haven't **been to** this website in a while
>
> I haven't **gone to** this website in a while

Another view treats websites like documents, bulletin boards, or archives:

> I haven't **viewed** this website in a while
>
> I haven't **opened** this website in a while
>
> I haven't **checked** this website in a while
>
> I haven't **caught up on** this website in a while.

and others.

You can use "got on" but usually for sites that require some kind of authentication (like a username/password) to access your account:

> I can't **get on** the company website.  It says my password is expired.
>
> Can you **get on** Facebook?  I posted all the pictures of us there.

Answer (score 3):

Your second example sounds unnatural and instead implies that you haven't visited the website because you were not able to connect to the website, not for lack of trying (for example, if the website had been offline for months).

I would suggest either:

> I've not **viewed** this website for months.

> I've not **been to** this website for months.

Or, for a website for which you have an account, perhaps:

> I've not **logged into** this website for months.